# Accessing db information from config.ini for db connection and query table data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using shared hosting. Here I created config.ini file 
in `/home/kkits996/private/config.ini` with connection information.

2. copied `dbconnection.php` and `dbconcheck.php` in default folder
   When i run dbconcheck to check the dbconnection and retrive table data 
   its not showing the fetch results from the table cruduser
   and echo values from the table is not showing.

   dbconnect.php

   ```
   <?php
   function db_connect() {

       // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
       static $connection;

       // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
       if(!isset($connection)) {
           // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
           //    $config = parse_ini_file('/home/kkits996/private/config.ini'); 
           $connection = mysqli_connect($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
       }

       // If connection was not successful, handle the error
       if($connection === false) {
           // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
           return mysqli_connect_error(); 
       }
       return $connection;
   }

   // Connect to the database
   $connection = db_connect();

   // Check connection
   if ($connection->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
   }
   ?>
   ```

   dbconcheck.php

   ```
   <?php
   echo "1111";
   require_once('dbconnect.php');
   echo "2222";
   //$sql = "SELECT username,password FROM cruduser";
   //$result = $connection->query($sql);
   //$result = $connection->prepare($sql);
   //$result->execute();
   $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM cruduser where id=6");
   $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $c1 = $row1['username'];
   $c2 = $row1['password'];
   echo $c1;
   echo $c2;
   echo "3333";
   ?>
   ```

Comment: You might want to edit your post to fix the formatting of your code.. it's very difficult to read as is.

Comment: formatted the code